# Issues with loading image blob in a separate script

Tags: php

I want to load image, but the solution that I can get so far is loading a separate script with db - reconnection.

I have a init.php file which basically start up the application with db connection. 
looks something like this.

```
 if(!isset($_SESSION)){
     session_start();
}
//error_reporting(0); //dont show path name errors when error occurs

//  include required files
require 'databases/connect.php';
```

I have this line of code which tells the blob script to retrieve image Data

```
   <img src="../core/functions/images.php?image_id=<?php echo $responses[$i]['product_id']; ?>" height="150" width="180" alt=""/>
```

And this is the problem script that re-connect db again and then retrieve the image data. If I do not reconnect the db, the mysql script will fail. Any help on this, so I don't need to reconnect db?

```
$connect_error = "Sry, we are working on an error, try later";
mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die($connect_error);
mysql_select_db('SJ3') or die($connect_error);

 if(isset($_GET['image_id'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT imageType,imageData FROM output_images WHERE imageId=" . $_GET['image_id'];
    $result = mysql_query("$sql") or die("<b>Error:</b> Problem on Retrieving Image BLOB<br/>" . mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    header("Content-type: " . $row["imageType"]);

    echo $row["imageData"];
}
?>
```

Comment: its a new page it needs a connection (will be recycled if it can), you could put `require 'databases/connect.php';` in images.php

Comment: then it didnt solve the problem, it's reconnecting the db again, which I am trying to avoid here.

Comment: db connections are not persistent, reconnection is what you have to do.